# How to mock variable in a test case

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've a function that I want to write unit tests for (function is a part of class `A`):

```
def funcA(self):
    variable = self.attributes.method() 
    logger.info("Log")
```

this function is called from another function that initialize Class and save its object to `self.attributes` variable.

```
def funcB(self):
    self.attributes = B()
    # call funcA if certain criteria is met
```

and I have implementation of `method` function inside of `B` class definition.

How can I now write unit test for `funcA`?

I've tried to do it like this:

```
import classA as a
def test_funcA(self) -> None:
    self.classA = a.A()
    method_return = self.classA.funcA()
```

this gives me error `'A' object has no attribute 'attributes'`

I also tried to mock this missing attribute by:
`a.A.attributes = Mock(return_value={})`

but then I got different error `TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable`

I guess I need to somehow mock class B and the method function, so that my main method that I'm testing will just take the mocked return and assert if it logs correct message, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial intuition about setting the `attributes` directly is probably the way to go. You should set the proper value - with the relevant properties `B()` would have returned.

Inside your test, you can do something in the form of `self.classA.attributes = Bunch(mathod=lambda: "value for variable", another_attribute_used_inside_funcA = 20)`. See [bunch library](https://pypi.org/project/bunch/).